# How to store historical data using Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, historical-db

I am new to Django and am trying to figure out how to store historical data and be able to reference any data point from a date in the past. Say I want to store data on a kids height change as he grows and be able to compare his height at day 400 to his height at day 6xx. How would I set this up in Django? Would there need to be a foreign key relationship between height and the kid?

Comment: This is basic relational database modelling, nothing Python nor Django specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [simple history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) app.
According to the [docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/usage.html) you need to add a `HistoricalRecords` field to your model:

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class Kid(models.Model):
     id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     height = models.IntegerField()
     history = HistoricalRecords()
```

And then all model changes will be stored in the separate table.
You can use this field in the code or use admin views to check historical records and [retrieve](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=retrieve#reverting-the-model).

Comment: I have a question about that lib - when you `.save()` the instance of the model - it saves the whole instance in the `HistoricalRecords` or just the time of its last update? You can get the previous version of this instance before update via HR? It is not clearly written in the docs.

Comment: @Chiefir yes it saves the whole instance and can be [retrieved](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=retrieve#reverting-the-model).

Comment: @Chiefir were you able to check this solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: I did not test this solution, was just curious how this lib works. May be will use it in future if I need this functionality :)

Answer (score 2):

Forget about Django's ORM (which is really just a very thin wrapper over your SQL database) and think in terms of relational database. Here you obviously have two entities: "kid" and "height". You also have the following relationships: a "kid" has zero, one or many "height", a "height" belongs to one single "kid". This indeed translates to a "kid" table  `kid(+id, name, dob, ...)` and a "height" table with a foreign key on `kid`: `height(+id, kid_id, date, value)`.

How to write this using Django's orm is quite straighforward so I'll leave it to you.